# Learning Kubernetes

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, aks

So I am trying to learn Kubernetes on Azure so doing the tutorial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-acr

Problem is on the login step the command does not work:

> Log in to the container registry To use the ACR instance, you must
> first log in. Use the az acr login command and provide the unique name
> given to the container registry in the previous step.
>
> Azure CLI
>
> Copy
>
> *az acr login --name `<acrName>`*
>
> The command returns a Login Succeeded message once completed.

What i get returned is that this command is not supported in Azure CLI!

> jeff@Azure:~$ az acr login --name Z-------01

> **This command requires running the docker daemon, which is not supported in Azure Cloud Shell. You may want to use 'az acr login -n
> Z-------01 --expose-token' to get an access token, which does not
> require Docker to be installed.**

I have done that yet from there I still cannot seem to get logged in to move on to the next step.  Any advice?  I don't mind using token but couldn't find the proper syntax to use it successfully.  Love how their simple tutorial doesn't even work, not confidence inspiring to say the least Microsoft.

Please note I put the - in to mask the name.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what i was doing wrong. To do this you need to download and install Azure CLI to your local OS, not run command from cloud shell in azure (which is how i prefer to do things so is my default, well Powershell really this is new foray into Azure CLI) To get the Azure CLI local go here: [docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/…](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=azure-cli) It does say that at the top after rereading it, guess it was late and i was tired so missed it. I hope that helps some other newbs who miss that, enjoy! –